# Apache Flink relating/caching data options

Tags: caching, apache-flink, flink-streaming

This is a very broad question, I’m new to Flink and looking into the possibility of using it as a replacement for a current analytics engine.

The scenario is, data collected from various equipment, the data is received As a JSON encoded string with the format of {“location.attribute”:value, “TimeStamp”:value}

For example a unitary traceability code is received for a location, after which various process parameters are received in a real-time stream. The analysis is to be ran over the process parameters however the output needs to include a relation to a traceability code. For example {“location.alarm”:value, “location.traceability”:value, “TimeStamp”:value}

What method does Flink use for caching values, in this case the current traceability code whilst running analysis over other parameters received at a later time?

I’m mainly just looking for the area to research as so far I’ve been unable to find any examples of this kind of scenario. Perhaps it’s not the kind of process that Flink can handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natural way to do this sort of thing with Flink would be to key the stream by the location, and then use keyed state in a `ProcessFunction` (or `RichFlatMapFunction`) to store the partial results until ready to emit the output.

With a keyed stream, you are guaranteed that every event with the same key will be processed by the same instance. You can then use [keyed state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state), which is effectively a sharded key/value store, to store per-key information.

The [Apache Flink training](https://training.ververica.com/) includes some explanatory material on [keyed streams](https://training.ververica.com/lessons/keyed-streams.html) and [working with keyed state](https://training.ververica.com/lessons/stateful.html), as well as [an exercise](https://training.ververica.com/exercises/rideEnrichment-flatmap.html) [or two](https://training.ververica.com/exercises/rideEnrichment-processfunction.html) that explore how to use these mechanisms to do roughly what you need.

Alternatively, you could do this with the Table or SQL API, and implement this as a join of the stream with itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This answer has me around half way, however the part that still has me confused is the following.

Keying on the location is not a problem, however, when then using a keyed state, this seems to only allow for the caching of a single attributes value(s). 

So if against that location, i want to cache the traceability code and a collection of voltage values up until the point of receiving some other attribute signalling the end of the process, it seems i cant manage the keyed state for all within the same scope. Like a sharded user defined dictionary

Comment: To maybe clarify further, i receive an attribute of traceability code, then an attribute of active, then multiple messages containing the voltage of the equipment. I want to cache only those voltages while active is equal to true. When it is no longer active, i want to perform some assessment over the voltages and return the result with the associated traceability code. With keyed state, i dont see how these things can be accessible to each other

Comment: It sounds like you need to process some of the attributes in temporal order. Are you guaranteed they will arrive in order, or do you need to take care to sort them?

Comment: I'm not understanding what the challenge is regarding connecting the different events together. Don't all of the messages that relate to one another have some sort of identifier in common?

Comment: The issue i was having was caching all of the data, from the various attributes, until some trigger point at which the evaluation could take place. I've worked around that by using a class within the keyed state and storing the required related data within the class object. Whether that is considered the correct way to do it within Flink im not sure, but it workds

Comment: You just need to be careful to either make sure it's a valid POJO class -- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/types_serialization.html#rules-for-pojo-types -- or an Avro class, so that Flink will be able to do automatic schema evolution and state migration for you during stateful upgrades you may do in the future.